# Can't connect to HTTPS sites using Socket HTTP-proxy

Tags: java, sockets, http, https, proxy

I have written a simple class extends Thread, used to receive user request, send it to HTTP-proxy server, runs on my Android device, get response and send it back to user:

```
public class ProxyThread extends Thread {
private Socket clientSocket = null;

public ProxyThread(Socket socket) {
    super("ProxyThread");
    this.clientSocket = socket;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        // Read request
        InputStream incomingIS = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[8196];
        int len = incomingIS.read(b);
        if (len > 0) {
            System.out.println("REQUEST"
                    + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "-------");
            System.out.println(new String(b, 0, len));
            // Write Request
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.136.96", 8080);
            OutputStream outgoingOS = socket.getOutputStream();
            outgoingOS.write(b, 0, len);
            // Send back
            OutputStream incomingOS = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            InputStream outgoingIS = socket.getInputStream();
            for (int length; (length = outgoingIS.read(b)) != -1; ) {
                incomingOS.write(b, 0, length);
                System.out.println("Answer"
                        + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "-------");
                System.out.println(new String(b, 0, len));
            }

            incomingOS.close();
            outgoingIS.close();
            outgoingOS.close();
            incomingIS.close();

            socket.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("closed");
}
```

I used FireFox to connect to the server (localhost:80). So it works fine with sites using HTTP (example http://info.cern.ch/), but it is not for sites using HTTPS.

For example i try to connect https://facebook.com.

FireFox sends a request:

```
CONNECT www.facebook.com:443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
Host: www.facebook.com:443
```

Proxy sends back a response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
Host: www.facebook.com:443
```

I don't know why FireFox does show nothing, but maybe it just can't recive an response from my server (localhost:80) and i don't know why.

Comment: BTW When I connected directly to android proxy-server everything works well.

Comment: It is too few known what the proxy is actually doing. I cannot see in your code how the response is  exactly constructed and what happens after the response got send - i.e. forwarding data between client and server in both directions. .In any case the response send by the proxy contains lots of lines which should not harm, but which do not make sense in a proxy response, i.e. Host header, User-Agent, Proxy-Connection

Comment: I am using proxy app dowloaded from Play Market, only thing I know that direct connection works well.

Comment: Now I understand. The approach you use with plain HTTP is already flawed but might work in many cases (short requests). For HTTPS though it cannot work: with HTTPS you need to first read the request (CONNECT) from the client and forward it to the proxy, Then you need to read the response (HTTP/1.1 200 ..) and forward it to the client. And then you need to forward all the following __bidirectional__ traffic between client and server __in both direction__ until these close the connection. Instead you expect only the server to send data, which is wrong.

Comment: Ok, I will try to fix it. If I succeed I'll post the solution code here. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: It's because you are not sending any traffic after the initial request and response. CONNECT method creates a connection *through* your proxy directly to the server, so the client can send encrypted data to the server, and get encrypted data back, and you have to send and receive the data even though you cannot understand any of it because it's encrypted.